# Extracting localhost

Tags: 22.04, localhost

I am trying to transfer my website which is currently on localhost to my domain. To do this, I need to extract the files from localhost and compress it into a zip file.

I have doubts about the possibility of this, so if you have a solution for my original problem, which is to transfer my localhost to a domain, please comment!

By the way, I have a Hostinger domain and Hostinger's Single Web Hosting. I am using Ubuntu 22.04. *And I don't know the physical location to localhost!*

**Important**: I do not want to make any more purchases!

Comment: Why do you need to compress the files?
Can't you just use `scp` for transferring the files?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't necessarily need a zip archive and can access the server via ssh, `scp` is probably the fastest and easiest way to transfer data.

**Example:**

```sh
scp -r /your/local/path/to/directory username@<IP_ADDRESS>:/your/path/on/server
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But first, I don't know the physical location to localhost. Secondly, I don't know Hostinger well, so I don't know how to fill in `username` and `IP_ADDRESS`.

Comment: Then you have to figure out *where* on you computer the stuff you want to transfer is located, and you have to figure out the username and ip or hostname. There's no way around this.

Comment: @vidarlo Can you provide some suggestions as on how to do this?

Comment: For the first point - you have done something to create a website. Where are those files? What did you do to create the website? For the second and third - read the documentation from hostinger.